# If A is a vector subset of B, how can I find the indices of A within B in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, indexing

Consider a row vector A and row vector B. For example:

```
A = [1 2 3 7 8 10 12];
B = [1 1 2 2 2 3 5 6 6 7 7 7 8 8 10 10 10 11 12 12 12 13 15 16 18 19];
```

A has previously been checked to be a subset of B. By subset, I specifically mean that all elements in A can be found in B. I know that elements in A will not ever repeat. However, the elements in B are free to repeat as many or as few times as they like. I checked this condition using:

```
is_subset = all(ismember(A,B));
```

With all that out of the way, I need to know the indices of the elements of A within B including the times when these elements repeat within B. For the example A and B above, the output would be:

C = [1 2 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 21];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to find the relevant logical indices. Then convert them to linear indices using [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html).

```
C = find(ismember(B,A));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the difference of each element of A with B, and get the indices you want. Something like below:

```
A = [1 2 3 7 8 10 12];
B = [1 1 2 2 2 3 5 6 6 7 7 7 8 8 10 10 10 11 12 12 12 13 15 16 18 19];
C = [1 2 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 21];
tol = 10^-3 ;
N = length(A) ;
iwant = cell(N,1) ;
for i = 1:N
    idx = abs(A(i)-B)<=tol ;
    iwant{i} = find(idx) ;
end
iwant = [iwant{:}] ;
```